# Should you share psycopg3 AsyncConnections between tasks in Python?

Tags: postgresql, python-asyncio, psycopg2, database-cursor, psycopg3

Psycopg3 supports async connections and async cursors. I have multiple writer tasks writing to a database. Should I pass each of those tasks the same `AsyncConnection`? If not, should I pass them the same `AsyncCursor`? Or should I make a new connection in each of the functions?

eg: below, would I send `aconn` to each of my tasks? Or `cur`? Or should this code be in each of the tasks?

```
async with await psycopg.AsyncConnection.connect() as aconn:
    async with aconn.cursor() as cur:
        await cur.execute(...)
```

All of the example code I could find had only one task being created. Thanks!

Comment: I cannot give you a good answer since I have not tried it, but have you considered using psycopg3's connection pooling?  https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/advanced/pool.html#connection-pools

Comment: I considered it but it appears to not support async connections - just synchronous ones - so it wouldn't return control to the event loop during the writing process

Comment: The docs say there is an async connection pool implementation:  https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/api/pool.html#psycopg_pool.AsyncConnectionPool